# Detecting if a key-value pair exists within a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, key-value

I cannot find a way to determine if a key-value pair exists in a hash.

```
h4 = { "a" => 1, "d" => 2, "f" => 35 }
```

I can use `Hash#has_value?` and `Hash#has_key?` to find information about a key or a value individually, but how can I check if a pair exists?

Psuedo-code of what I'm after:

```
if h4.contains_pair?("a", 1)
```

Comment: Can the value possibly be `nil`?

Comment: Thanks for the note sawa! Jordan already addressed both scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use this:

```
h4['a'] == 1
```

It seems excessive to me, but you could monkey-patch Hash with a method like so:

```
class Hash
  def contains_pair?(key, value)
    key?(key) && self[key] == value
  end
end
```

Comment: Gah, I thought you could only set hash values with that syntax--didn't think to try `==`.  I wish you wouldn't have seen this thread Jordan... now you know how much of a noob I really am.  I'll mark your answer as correct shortly as it is the most concise.

Comment: Jordan, are you by chance available to glance at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951060/ruby-array-of-hashes-nested-html-menu-from-hash-values-without-writing-dupli pretty please?  I'm hitting a wall on an important project to me and so far after a couple days I don't have any reaction on SO.

Comment: @sawa's comment on the question was alluding to the fact that `h[k] == v` does not work if `v` can equal `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

I confess to starting down a road and then wondering where it might take me. This may not be the best way of determining if a key/value pair is present in a hash (how could one improve on @Jordan's answer?), but I learned something along the way.

**Code**

```
def pair_present?(h,k,v)
  Enumerable.instance_method(:include?).bind(h).call([k,v])
end
```

**Examples**

```
h = { "a"=>1, "d"=>2, "f"=>35 }

pair_present?(h,'a',1)
  #=> true

pair_present?(h,'f',36)
  #=> false

pair_present?(h,'hippopotamus',2)
  #=> false
```

**Discussion**

We could of course convert the hash to an array and then apply [Array#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
h.to_a.include?(['a', 1])
  #=> true
```

but that has the downside of creating a temporary array. It would be nice if the class `Hash` had such an instance method, but it does not. One might think [Hash#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-include-3F) might be used for that, but it just takes one argument, a key.<sup>1</sup>.

The method [Enumerable#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F) does what we want, and of course `Hash` `include`s the `Enumerable` module. We can invoke that method in various  ways.

*Bind `Enumerable#include?` to the hash and call it*

This was of course my answer:

```
Enumerable.instance_method(:include?).bind(h).call([k,v])
```

Use the method [Method#super_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-super_method), which was introduced in v2.2.

```
h.method(:include?).super_method.call(['a',1])
  #=> true
h.method(:include?).super_method.call(['a',2])
  #=> false
```

Note that:

```
h.method(:include?).super_method
  #=> #<Method: Object(Enumerable)#include?>
```

*Do the `alias_method`/`remove_method` merry-go-round*

```
Hash.send(:alias_method, :temp, :include?)
Hash.send(:remove_method, :include?)
h.include?(['a',1])
  #=> true
h.include?(['a',2])
  #=> false
Hash.send(:alias_method, :include?, :temp)
Hash.send(:remove_method, :temp)
```

*Convert the hash to an enumerator and invoke `Enumerable#include?`*

```
h.to_enum.include?(['a',1])
  #=> true
h.to_enum.include?(['a',2])
  #=> false
```

This works because the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html) also `include`s `Enumerable`.

<sup>1 `Hash#include?` is the same as both [Hash#key?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) and [Hash#has_key?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F). It makes me wonder why `include?` isn't used for the present purpose, since determining if a hash has a given key is well-covered.</sup>

Comment: Whoa, good stuff.  I am glad I asked the question instead of shying away from it because I thought it was too simple.  This is really good stuff, thanks Cary!

Answer (score 0):

How about using Enumerable [any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

```
h4 = { "a" => 1, "d" => 2, "f" => 35 }
h4.any? {|k,v| k == 'a' && v == 1 }
```

Comment: It seems a little bizarre to iterate over the entire Hash when we can access the key directly in O(1) time.