# Ruby - Array of hashes - Nested HTML menu from hash values without writing duplicates

Tags: html, ruby, hash, nested

I have a relatively large hash where the values for all keys within are array of hashes (see below for sample layout).  I have spent the last 4.5 hours attempting to write out HTML for my Rails application and I am seriously about to cry as I've gone round in circles with nothing really to show for it!

Any help is *greatly* appreciated and thank you in advance for your time!

**Specific Problems Encountered**

1. Chapters/verses appear for books that they do not align to.
2. I'm also not able to de-duplicate entries, so 'Chapter 4', for example, is appearing multiple times (instead of it appearing once, with mulitple chapter/verse references nested beneath)

**Desired Solution Criteria**

1. The HTML needs to be written in 3 layers/nested (1st layer/div containing Book Name (e.g. Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus), 2nd layer/div containing chapter  and 3rd layer/div containing verse)
2. Chapters and verses must align (e.g. Exodus 2:7 should not be written to the Genesis chapter 2 menu).
3. Book names should be written in the order of `hsh`'s keys (e.g. Genesis followed by Exodus followed by Leviticus as opposed to alphabetical order)

**Data Format:**

```
hsh = { :genesis =>
             [
                 {:id => 1, :verse => 'Genesis 4:12'},
                 {:id => 1, :verse => 'Genesis 4:23-25'},
                 {:id => 2, :verse => 'Genesis 6:17'}
             ],
        :exodus =>
             [
                 {:id => 5, :verse => 'Exodus 2:7'},
                 {:id => 3, :verse => 'Exodus 2:14-15'},
                 {:id => 4, :verse => 'Exodus 12:16'}
             ],
        :leviticus =>
             [
                 {:id => 2, :verse => 'Leviticus 11:19-21'},
                 {:id => 7, :verse => 'Leviticus 15:14-31'},
                 {:id => 7, :verse => 'Leviticus 19:11-12'}
             ]
     }
```

**Desired Output HTML** [Shortened for Brevity]

```
<div class="submenu">
    <a href="#">Genesis</a>
    <div class="lvl-2">
        <div>
            <div class="submenu">
                <a>Chapter 4</a>
                <div class="lvl-3">
                    <div>
                        <a onclick="load('1')"><span>ID 1</span> Verse 12</a>
                        <a onclick="load('1')"><span>ID 1</span> Verse 23-25</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="submenu">
                <a>Chapter 6</a>
                <div class="lvl-3">
                    <div> <a onclick="load('2')"><span>ID 2</span> Verse 17</a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu">
        <a href="#">Exodus</a>
        <div class="lvl-2">
            <div>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <a>Chapter 2</a>
                    <div class="lvl-3">
                        <div>
                            <a onclick="load('5')"><span>ID 5</span> Verse 7</a>
                            <a onclick="load('3')"><span>ID 3</span>Verse 14-15</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <a>Chapter 12</a>
                    <div class="lvl-3">
                        <div>
                            <a onclick="load('4')"><span>ID 4</span> Verse 16</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ## Shortened for brevity (Leviticus references excluded)
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
final_html = String.new

hsh.each do |book, verse_array|

    verse_array.each do |reference|

      book = reference[:verse].split(' ').first           # => "Genesis"
      full_verse = reference[:verse].split(' ').last      # => "4:12"
      chapter = full_verse.split(':').first               # => "4"
      verse = full_verse.split(':').first                 # => "12"

      # Failing Miserably at appending the right HTML to the final_html string here...
      # final_html << "<div class=\"submenu\">"
      # final_html << ...
      # final_html << ...

    end
end
```

Finally, note that there are no duplicate chapter/verse combinations (e.g. Genesis 4:12 will never appear a second time). It's also worth noting that both chapters and verses need to be sorted numerically and ascending.

Comment: All, I realize that the code I've provided doesn't show alot of effort, but I assure you I've spent hours trying all kinds of iterations strategies, etc.  Right now in Rubymine I have about 210 lines of garbage, mostly commented out, and trying to explain all the techniques I've tried would make this question too long.  It's already arguably on the lengthier side.  Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: Hi Dinesh, not explicitly.  I have iterated over the array of hashes in many different ways and I am generating HTML without errors--it's just horribly out of order and duplicated.  Thanks for reaching out.  Really appreciate it.  Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case with such problems, it becomes much easier to solve once you've put the data into a "shape" that closely resembles your desired output. Your output is a nested tree structure, so your data should be, too. Let's do that first. Here's your data:

```
data = {
  genesis: [
    { id: 1, verse: "Genesis 4:12" },
    { id: 1, verse: "Genesis 4:23-25" },
    { id: 2, verse: "Genesis 6:17" }
  ],
  exodus: [
    { id: 5, verse: "Exodus 2:7" },
    # ...
  ],
  # ...
}
```

And, setting aside the HTML for now, here's the structure we want:

```
Genesis
  Chapter 4
    ID 1 - Verse 12
    ID 1 - Verse 23-25
  Chapter 6
    ID 2 - Verse 17
Exodus
  Chapter 2
    ID 5 - Verse 7
    ...
...
```

The first thing I notice about your data is that it has a level of nesting you don't need. Since the `:verse` values contain the book name, we don't the keys from the outer hash (`:genesis` et al) and we can just flatten all of the inner hashes into a single array:

```
data.values.flatten
# => [ { id: 1, verse: "Genesis 4:12" },
#      { id: 1, verse: "Genesis 4:23-25" },
#      { id: 2, verse: "Genesis 6:17" }
#      { id: 5, verse: "Exodus 2:7" },
#      # ... ]
```

Now we need a method to extract the book, chapter, and verse from the `:verse` strings. You can use `String#split` if you want, but a Regexp is a good choice too:

```
VERSE_EXPR = /(.+)\s+(\d+):(.+)$/

def parse_verse(str)
  m = str.match(VERSE_EXPR)
  raise "Invalid verse string!" if m.nil?
  book, chapter, verse = m.captures
  { book: book, chapter: chapter, verse: verse }
end

flat_data = data.values.flatten.map do |id:, verse:|
  { id: id }.merge(parse_verse(verse))
end
# => [ { id: 1, book: "Genesis", chapter: "4", verse: "12" },
#      { id: 1, book: "Genesis", chapter: "4", verse: "23-25" },
#      { id: 2, book: "Genesis", chapter: "6", verse: "17" },
#      { id: 5, book: "Exodus", chapter: "2", verse: "7" },
#      # ... ]
```

Now it's easy to group the data by book:

```
books = flat_data.group_by {|book:, **| book }
# => { "Genesis" => [
#        { id: 1, book: "Genesis", chapter: "4", verse: "12" },
#        { id: 1, book: "Genesis", chapter: "4", verse: "23-25" },
#        { id: 2, book: "Genesis", chapter: "6", verse: "17" }
#      ],
#      "Exodus" => [
#        { id: 5, book: "Exodus", chapter: "2", verse: "7" },
#        # ...
#      ],
#      # ...
#    }
```

...and within each book, by chapter:

```
books_chapters = books.map do |book, verses|
  [ book, verses.group_by {|chapter:, **| chapter } ]
end
# => [ [ "Genesis",
#        { "4" => [ { id: 1, book: "Genesis", chapter: "4", verse: "12" },
#                   { id: 1, book: "Genesis", chapter: "4", verse: "23-25" } ],
#          "6" => [ { id: 2, book: "Genesis", chapter: "6", verse: "17" } ]
#        }
#      ],
#      [ "Exodus",
#        { "2" => [ { id: 5, book: "Exodus", chapter: "2", verse: "7" },
#                   # ... ],
#          # ...
#        }
#      ],
#      # ...
#    ]
```

You'll notice that since we called `map` on `books` our final result is an Array, not a Hash. You could call `to_h` on it to make it a Hash again, but for our purposes it's not necessary (iterating over an Array of key-value pairs works the same as iterating over a Hash).

It looks a little messy, but you can see that the structure is there: Verses nested within chapters nested within books. Now we just need to turn it into HTML.

> An aside, for the sake of our friends with disabilities: The correct
>   HTML element to use for nested tree structures is `<ul>` or `<ol>`. If
>   you have some requirement to use `<div>`s instead you can, but
>   otherwise use the right element for the job—users who use
>   accessibility devices will thank you. (Many articles have been written
>   on styling such trees, so I won't go into it, but for a start you can
>   hide the bullets with `list-style-type: none;`.)

I don't have a Rails app at my disposal, so to generate the HTML I'll just use ERB from the Ruby standard library. It will look more-or-less identical in Rails except for how you pass the variable to the view.

```
require "erb"

VIEW = <<END
<ul>
<% books.each do |book_name, chapters| %>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><%= book_name %></a>
    <ul>
    <% chapters.each do |chapter, verses| %>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Chapter <%= chapter %></a>
        <ul>
        <% verses.each do |id:, verse:, **| %>
          <li>
            <a onclick="load(<%= id %>)">ID <%= id %>: Verse <%= verse %></a>
          </li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
END

def render(books)
   b = binding
   ERB.new(VIEW, nil, "<>-").result(b)
end

puts render(books_chapters)
```

And here's the result as an HTML snippet:

```html
<ul>

  <li>
    <a href="#">Genesis</a>
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Chapter 4</a>
        <ul>

          <li>
            <a onclick="load(1)">ID 1: Verse 12</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a onclick="load(1)">ID 1: Verse 23-25</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Chapter 6</a>
        <ul>

          <li>
            <a onclick="load(2)">ID 2: Verse 17</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">Exodus</a>
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Chapter 2</a>
        <ul>

          <li>
            <a onclick="load(5)">ID 5: Verse 7</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a onclick="load(3)">ID 3: Verse 14-15</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Chapter 12</a>
        <ul>

          <li>
            <a onclick="load(4)">ID 4: Verse 16</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">Leviticus</a>
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Chapter 11</a>
        <ul>

          <li>
            <a onclick="load(2)">ID 2: Verse 19-21</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Chapter 15</a>
        <ul>

          <li>
            <a onclick="load(7)">ID 7: Verse 14-31</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Chapter 19</a>
        <ul>

          <li>
            <a onclick="load(7)">ID 7: Verse 11-12</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Finally, here it is in action on repl.it: https://repl.it/Duhm

Comment: I love you more than you have any idea...  Thanks so much for this detailed, lengthy, and probably exhausting write up.  REALLY appreciate your time.  I'll try this tonight or soon!

Comment: Jordan,  I don't think I have permission to PM yet, otherwise I'd ask direct.  Are you allowed to accept donations for your help on SO?  If so, please provide your PayPal or similar!

Comment: Thanks Jordan.  This worked perfectly.  Note that on earlier versions of Ruby the keyboard argument syntax (e.g. `|id:, verse:|`, `{|book:, **| book }`, etc.) shown in the answer will not work.  Instead, values will have to manually be extracted from the hash.  You saved me again... and I learned some things from your approach.